# VB.NET Communicating with console app and sending parameters

Tags: vb.net, console-application, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm creating myself a GUI for a program that can be used in CMD, a CLI.
The program has the following input:

```
Ex: extractor.exe filename.rar newfilename.zip -c <password for achive>
filename.rar = the original file 
newfilename.zip = the file to be created with new format
-c a command meaning key
<password...> - here comes the archive password.
```

It's great on CMD, but I would like to make a GUI.
I do it in VB and so:
For filename.rar I have one textbox that goes filled with a path specified by user using OpenFileDialog1.
For newfilename.zip I use a savefiledialog and a textbox: The textbox gets the path specified by user

Another textbox3 for the password and a button to call extractor.exe:

How can I pass these arguments to extractor?

I have tried with

```
argument = textbox1.text + textbox2.text + "-c" + textbox3.text
```

The program starts but simply closes as it simply doesn't get the parameters.

I have also tried this:

```
Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo
        Dim procname = "extractor.exe"
        Dim filename = TextBox1.Text
        Dim newfile = TextBox3.Text
        Dim key = TextBox2.Text
        Dim args = ("extract" + filename + newfile + "-k" + key)
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(procname, args)
        Dim proc As New Process()
        proc.StartInfo = psi
        proc.Start()
```

No luck. I'm able to send 1 parameter if I do like
argument = "extract" but i have multiple arguments that needs to be fetched from textboxes....is there a way?

Thanks!

Comment: try system print the args and see if there's proper spacing

Comment: you will need to wrap filenames with spaces in quotes, and maybe the whole argument set (the CLI isnt that clear).  Something like this works: `cmd = String.Format(" {0} {1}{2}{1} -{3} {4}", arg1, quote, arg2, arg3, arg4)`

Comment: I tried with this method, if no parameter is passed, extractor.exe will post a kind of "map" how to use program. And With this example, it simply shows that map, meaning that the parameters are not sent, just the app starts.

Comment: before `proc.Start()` add this: `Console.WriteLine(args)` then [edit] your question to show the output you copy from the output window

Comment: I managed it myself... You need to dim extract as a text = Dim extract as "extract" and it would work :) Thanks all.